Stream RPI 5 cameras to other PC's Python script
I have two RPI cameras connected to CSI ports. I can access them via libcamera-vid, no problem. My goal is to stream those two cameras to another PC.
So far I tried, for example:
gst-launch-1.0 -v libcamerasrc ! video/x-raw, format=RGBx, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! timeoverlay ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=I420 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.102 port=5600 sync=false async=true

Which was not caught by either Python :
import cv2

def receive():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("udpsrc port=5600 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print('Empty frame')
            continue
        cv2.imshow('receive', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Don't forget to close the window when done!

receive()

Or by VLC. If I try to read UDP on incoming PC side - it shows me data incoming, so at least with networking, its okay. I even opened 5600 UDP ports (incoming and outcoming (This was done on WIN10)).
I've read on internet people use rpicamsrc, but I was unable to even install it. I understand, there are some problems with Raspberry 5? I remember streaming well with my 3B+ and even Zero W.
On top of that - would it be possible to compress at least one camera to x265?
